# Steps fluctuate when using Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I've developed a fitness app which uses Google Fit API to capture the users steps, calories and exercises minutes.

After rolling out the app, I've received a number of feedback that the steps fluctuate( e.g one moment it increases to 2300, next moment it drops to 1900). When the user cross check against the Google Fit app, they see the same.

I am using the Recording API to get the latest steps. I was only able too simulate this fluctuation when i shake the phone continuously ( instead of walking) in the attempt to increase the steps.

What I notice was the steps increase but within moments it drop back to the original step before i start shaking the phone. I was wondering if Google Fit some how detected that i was "cheating" and reverted the steps. Right after that when i walk normally, the steps still reverted. I takes a while before Fit begin to record my steps again.

However my users claimed that they did not shake the phone but instead walked normally but still face the issue.

Would really appreciate it if anyone could enlighten me as i couldn't find any post on this. TIA!

Comment: There could be a bug in your code.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your reply.but i noticed the same behavior when I'm using Google Fit app itself..

Comment: Maybe it has the same bug; I have about as much info about that app as I do yours.